# adding the same calculation with a difference but not changing TRUE/FALSE standard using r data table package

Tags: r, datatable

i have a dataset with 3 columns of interest: price_mid,quantity and value mid. the way to find price_mid is value/quanity. but some times you might have to multiply it by either a factor of 10 or 100.
now i have 3 potential formula's to bear in mind. I created a variable called valid to tell TRUE/FALSE as to weather the price_mid is equal to value/quantity *100 how could i simply extend this using data table package.

```
#This is the code i'm using.
dt[,valid := price_mid == (value_mid/quantity)*100]
```

how could i accomadate the 2 others without replacing the standard for TRUE/FALSE.

Thanks.

Comment: I think `data.table::fcase` fits your problem.

Comment: ```dt[,valid := fcase(price_mid == case1, value1, 
price_mid == case2, value2, 
price_mid == case3, value3]```

Comment: I can't find any clear R documentation in regards on how to use it @Eyayaw

Comment: oh thank you, didn't see you posted that only after i posted my reply

Comment: would you happen to know what this means?
`Error: 'fcase' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'`

Comment: You probably have an old version of data.table. `packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.12.9’`

Comment: As @Ian Campbell indicated you probably have an older version of the package. 
Try reinstalling the latest version via `install.packages("data.table")` or 
```# latest development version:
data.table::update.dev.pkg()```.

Comment: can i use ifelse instead with this function?